# Problems when building React App with Craco and Webpack 5 in VSCode

Tags: build, create-react-app, webpack-5, react-scripts, craco

I have a quite complex monorepo which I recently updated to Yarn 3. With it there where also so updates of the build specific packages like `webpack`, `react-scripts` and `@craco.craco`.

However, I have managed to get it all working but since recently, I get random

```
The "path" argument must be of type string. Received an instance of Buffer
```

errors, when running eg. `yarn workspace @apps/app1 build`. I have noticed that **reloading the window in VSCode** a couple of times, solves the issue.

What could be the cause of this error? Does anyone else experience similar issues?

Thanks!

###### Package versions

- `@craco/craco` : `v6.4.3`
- `webpack`: `v5.70.0`
- `react-scripts`: `v5.0.0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution

I'm now using the Provide Plugin and set

```
plugins: [
  new ProvidePlugin({ process: "process/browser.js" }),
]
```

in the `webpack.config` section.

Note the `.js`! This was getting rid of the error.